# Something for carrer growth and getting better in my art (like acting,music)

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, mantras, tantra

Any kind of mantra(which doesn't need initation) or anything else like any simple ritual etc

Comment: Perhaps try Sarasvati Devi mantra, for knowledge of all types, writing, music, arts :)

Comment: What's the mantra

Comment: If you google basic beginner puja mantras for Maa Sarasvati you’ll find boatloads of them :D

Comment: Sharada Bhujangam, a song in praise of Sharadamba would help it, Just read or listen it with devotion..